# Measure DC component in AC+DC mixed signal in flyback configuration with LTC3108

Tags: dc-dc-converter, flyback

I wonder how can read Input DC voltage After voltage dropped resistance(R1)

That's because this is Self-Ocillation Flyback converter,
In here, you can see the VIn is Ac voltage,
But I need to know Dc Level in this waveform.

Please tell me about the way to read Dc level

[image: Circuit simulator with readings and circuit diagram]

Comment: If I remember correctly, you can read the average voltage of a selected time span. Just select a whole period, and the AC part will average out.

Comment: Control-click on the waveform legend and you will be presented with a box saying among other things, average (DC) value.

Answer (score 1):

Zoom in on a section of the waveform that contains an integer multiple of cycles. Then Ctrl-click on the top legend for the variable or expression in question and you'll get the average and RMS in that interval.

For more precision you can right-click on the horizontal axis and set the left and right times to correspond an exact number of complete cycles. Then Ctrl-click on the top legend.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

read waveform Vp in both AC and DC coupled mode and take the difference.

Comment: Would you please give a more informantion by using Graph that is attached.